argocd 2.11.x with argocd-vault-pluging with aws secert manager configuration error
We upgrading argocd from 2.4 to 2.11 - from version 2.7 argocd-cm not longer supported.
added the following configmap and pathced the deployment
but getting an error
Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = plugin sidecar failed. error generating manifests in cmp: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error generating manifests: argocd-vault-plugin generate . failed exit status 1: Error: Must provide a supported Vault Type, received Usage: argocd-vault-plugin generate  [flags] Flags: -c, --config-path string path to a file containing Vault configuration (YAML, JSON, envfile) to use -h, --help help for generate -s, --secret-name string name of a Kubernetes Secret in the argocd namespace containing Vault configuration data in the argocd namespace of your ArgoCD host (Only available when used in ArgoCD). The namespace can be overridden by using the format : --verbose-sensitive-output enable verbose mode for detailed info to help with debugging. Includes sensitive data (credentials), logged to stderr
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cmp-plugin
data:
  avp.yaml: |
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: ConfigManagementPlugin
    metadata:
      name: argocd-vault-plugin
    spec:
      allowConcurrency: true
      discover:
        find:
          command:
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - "find . -name '*.yaml' | xargs -I {} grep \"<path\\|avp\\.kubernetes\\.io\" {} | grep ."
      generate:
        command:
          - argocd-vault-plugin
          - generate
          - "."
      lockRepo: false
---

and this is deployment patch
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: argocd-repo-server
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            name: cmp-plugin
          name: cmp-plugin
        - name: custom-tools
          emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
      - name: download-tools
        image: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8
        env:
          - name: AVP_VERSION
            value: 1.16.1
        command: [sh, -c]
        args:
          - >-
            curl -L https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-vault-plugin/releases/download/v$(AVP_VERSION)/argocd-vault-plugin_$(AVP_VERSION)_linux_amd64 -o argocd-vault-plugin &&
            chmod +x argocd-vault-plugin &&
            mv argocd-vault-plugin /custom-tools/
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /custom-tools
            name: custom-tools
      containers:
      - name: avp
        command: [/var/run/argocd/argocd-cmp-server]
        image: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 999
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/run/argocd
            name: var-files
          - mountPath: /home/argocd/cmp-server/plugins
            name: plugins
          - mountPath: /tmp
            name: tmp

          # Register plugins into sidecar
          - mountPath: /home/argocd/cmp-server/config/plugin.yaml
            subPath: avp.yaml
            name: cmp-plugin

          # Important: Mount tools into $PATH
          - name: custom-tools
            subPath: argocd-vault-plugin
            mountPath: /usr/local/bin/argocd-vault-plugin

